# Batch put() Limits

Tags: google-app-engine

Is there either a hard-limit, or a performance-degration limit for batch puts updating existing records? I have a task queue process where several thousand existing records are processed. At the end of the process loop, a BooleanProperty that is indexed is changed from False to True for all the records. Are there consequences to doing 5,000 records at a time versus nesting the batch put such that 10 iterations of updates are done 500 at a time 10? TIA -stevep

Answer (score 6):

The batching API will take care of splitting up large requests as needed, so you don't need to do that yourself.  The library manages limits such as the total size of a service call and the number of entities that can be put in a single call, and makes the appropriate number of calls to the service.  (According to the library code, this appears to be 1 megabyte and 500 entities per put call, but your app doesn't need to know that, and these might change.)  There's no advantage to splitting your put() calls, and you might accidentally make more service calls than necessary if you try.

Comment: One caveat: depending on the complexity of your entities (which is mostly determined by the number of properties, counting list properties multiple times), converting 5000 entities to protocol buffer objects (which is necessary before they can be serialized into the request) might use a lot of RAM.  The batch splitting that Dan Sanderson mentions, unfortunately, does not minimize the number of protobuf objects in memory simultaneously.  So if you experience memory errors, creating smaller batches yourself might actually help.