# App Engine Batch Put Too Large?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I occasionally get this error when I do batch puts.

> RequestTooLargeError: The request to API call datastore_v3.Put() was too large.

The call that triggers this does a `db.put` call on a list of 1000+ entities. Each entity has a single `db.TextProperty` field, filled with about 20,000 characters. Each entity also has a parent entity, although none of the entities in the list passed to `db.put` share a common parent. Each of the parent entities store about 10 integers and aren't very large.

My first instinct was to split up the number of entities being passed to `db.put`, but

Any ideas on the cause of this?

**Edit:** Splitting up the entities does work. For example, I can do this:

```
for entity in entities: entity.put()
```

But the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9351835/batch-put-limits) suggests that the number of entities being put shouldn't matter. So still confused.

Comment: Are any of your individual entities over 1MB? Have you tried splitting it up to verify it's not down to a single problematic entity?

Comment: None of the individual entities are over 1MB. I was able to put each of them individually.

Answer (score 4):

Remember that a quick test to find an entity's size is to try to write it to memcache. If it exceeds memcache's 1 meg limit the write will fail an you can catch the exception. May be of use if you follow Nick's suggestion to isolate the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I used a StringProperty until now and just ran into the same issue, when data stored in that property eventually grew too big (it just passed 1 MB). I was able to fix it for now with a JsonProperty where `compressed=True`. Might be an option.

Answer (score 0):

Is this batch update inside a transaction? if so, remember there is a 10 MB limit for a transaction [size](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/overview#Quotas_and_Limits)

Comment: Nope. Not inside a transaction.